# DRBL cluster with Open MPI 1.8.4

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, openmpi, drbd

When virtual/diskless node is used on DRBL cluster using Open MPI version 1.8.4, the error occurs:

```
Error: unknown option "--hnp-topo-sig"
```

I guess something with the topology signature and looks new. Any suggestions?
Typical command:

```
mpirun --machinefile machines -np 4 mpi_hello 

machinefile: node1 slots = 4
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that you are running different mpi versions on the nodes.  You can confirm if this is the case by ssh'ing into each node and running 'mpirun --version'